# Hibernate mapping to object that already exists

Tags: hibernate, mapping, foreign-keys

I have two classes, ServiceType and ServiceRequest. Every ServiceRequest must specify what kind of ServiceType it is. All ServiceType's are predefined in the database, and ServiceRequest is created at runtime by the client.

Here are my .hbm files:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class dynamic-insert="false" dynamic-update="false" mutable="true" name="xxx.model.entity.ServiceRequest" optimistic-lock="version" polymorphism="implicit" select-before-update="false">
    <id column="USER_ID" name="id">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="quantity">
        <column name="quantity" not-null="true"/>
    </property>
    <many-to-one cascade="all" class="xxx.model.entity.ServiceType" column="service_type" name="serviceType" not-null="false" unique="false"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

and

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class dynamic-insert="false" dynamic-update="false" mutable="true" name="xxx.model.entity.ServiceType" optimistic-lock="version" polymorphism="implicit" select-before-update="false">
    <id column="USER_ID" name="id">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="description">
        <column name="description" not-null="false"/>
    </property>
    <property name="cost">
        <column name="cost" not-null="true"/>
    </property>
    <property name="enabled">
        <column name="enabled" not-null="true"/>
    </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When I run this, I get

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

I think my problem is that when I create a new ServiceRequest object, ServiceType is one of its properties, and therefore when I'm saving ServiceRequest to the database, Hibernate attempts to insert the ServiceType object once again, and finds that it is already exists. If this is the case, how do I make it so that Hibernate points to the exists ServiceType instead of trying to insert it again?

The code throwing the error:

```
/* Get existing Service Type from database */
ServiceType st = DAOFactory.getDAOFactory().getServiceTypeDAO().getServiceType(newServiceTypeName);

/* Set the ServiceType of the new Service Request*/
newServiceRequest.setServiceType(st);

/* Error occurs inside this function which simply calls
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(sr);
    session.getTransaction().commit();  */
DAOFactory.getDAOFactory().getServiceRequestDAO().saveData(newServiceRequest);
return "newRequestDone";
```

Comment: what is the code you're running that causes that exception?

Comment: It happens when I attempt to save ServiceRequest. Its just a simple         session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(sr);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

Answer (score 0):

in the absence of the code that causes the exception, i'd say your problem is likely that you're trying to create a new `ServiceType` for each `ServiceRequest` whereas what you need to do is retrieve the existing `ServiceType` by id rather than adding a new one every time.

if this doesn't sound plausible, show your java code and i'll try and help further :)

---

further help : do your DAOs use the same hibernate session? entities loaded from one session and saved in another can cause problems unless you use `merge` instead of `save`.

Comment: I update my question to show the code. As you can see I'm requesting the ServiceType from the database, but then saving it again.

Comment: and yes, I'm using the same session for each DAO.

Comment: you could try merge() instead of save() anyway? or encapsulate the whole thing in a transaction? otherwise i'm out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: Nope, merge doesn't fix it :(. So Hibernate takes care of the situation where I'm saving an entity, that already exists in the database (ServiceRequest's property ServiceType in my case)?

Comment: it SHOULDN'T do. actually one more thing to try, take out the cascade="all" on your many-to-one mapping, see if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL exception doesn't really seem to match the assumption that it's trying to create a ServiceType that already exists.  Wouldn't you expect to see a unique constraint violation on the ServiceType table?  First thing I would check on seeing this is, does the FK target in the database match the hibernate mapping?  You can get things like this when your Entity for ServiceType is pointed to (BOB_DEV_SERVICE_TYPES) but the actual foreign key being enforced on the ServiceRequest goes to (TINA_TEST_SERVICE_TYPES)